# Is it possible to call matlab.engine from Flask webapp on Google Cloud?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, matlab-engine

I have a Flask app running in Google Cloud App Engine.  I want the user to be able to call MATLAB functions on their local instance - if they have MATLAB installed locally and the correct license, of course.

Running locally the app works well using matlab.engine, however, when deployed to google cloud platform it fails during build. Looking in the logs:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matlabengineforpython3_7

So I suspect it is because the server cannot import the required dlls etc. for the python matlab engine package to work.

Is there a way to pass the required files to google app engine? Is this approach even possible?

My users will always have a local copy of MATLAB, so I am trying to find a solution that avoids needing to pay for the MATLAB server license.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that any solution is possible that would avoid a Matlab server license.  Your server cannot access installed Matlab on the computers of your users.

To install non-Python software with App Engine you need to use a custom runtime with App Engine Flexible.  Check the GAE docs for more details.